# Portable way of programmatically sending an e-mail with an attachment under Unix

Tags: ruby, email, unix

I wish to have a portable Unix way of programmatically sending an e-mail with an attachment.  The "standard" Unix way of sending an e-mail seems to be mail(1), but there seems to be no portable way of specifying an attachment.  (Yes, I know that *some* versions of mail(1) have an `-a` or an `-A` option, but that's not standard, so I cannot rely on it.)

I'll be using ruby for this, but I want a *generic* solution, i.e., a special ruby configuration involving (say) using Net::SMTP and specifying details like the SMTP server &c. should *not* be in the application, but the application should issue a command like `mail <some other stuff here>` and from there the system should deliver the mail (with a suitable ~/.mailrc or whatever).

Comment: It would be nice to know why the downvotes.

Comment: What makes using “mail” generic but using “Net::SMTP” not? You seem to be asking for a mythical external program that doesn’t exist.

Comment: @Joe:  I'm a bit confused by this remark - mail(1) has been a part of Unix since I've ever known it (since ca. 1980 or so)., so I think it *can* be regarded as "standard".  I mentioned the mail(1) program for precisely this reason, but I'm willing to consider other solutions, as long as they don't involve installing some other random program that may exist on some specific version of some random platform.

Comment: Voting to close : "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, **tool, software library, tutorial** or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.". Please read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs. Tnx

Answer (score 0):

`mail` command will work only if it can find a SMTP host. There is a number of ways it can be done (sSMTP, Postfix, sendmail). The most "normal" way is to have `sendmail` running on your computer, which means `localhost` itself is an SMTP server. I don't know of a way of getting the SMTP configuration automatically if you don't have `sendmail` installed.

Therefore, assuming you know the SMTP server (`localhost` in this example), from [Tutorials Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_sending_email.htm) a pure Ruby mail attachment:

```
require 'net/smtp'

filename = "/tmp/test.txt"
# Read a file and encode it into base64 format
filecontent = File.read(filename)
encodedcontent = [filecontent].pack("m")   # base64

marker = "AUNIQUEMARKER"
body = <<EOF
This is a test email to send an attachement.
EOF

# Define the main headers.
part1 = <<EOF
From: Private Person <me@fromdomain.net>
To: A Test User <test@todmain.com>
Subject: Sending Attachement
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = #{marker}
--#{marker}
EOF

# Define the message action
part2 = <<EOF
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding:8bit

#{body}
--#{marker}
EOF

# Define the attachment section
part3 = <<EOF
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; name = \"#{filename}\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = "#{filename}"

#{encodedcontent}
--#{marker}--
EOF

mailtext = part1 + part2 + part3

# Let's put our code in safe area
begin 
   Net::SMTP.start('localhost') do |smtp|
      smtp.sendmail(mailtext, 'me@fromdomain.net', ['test@todmain.com'])
   end
rescue Exception => e  
   print "Exception occured: " + e  
end
```